# Elastic Search High Level Client Version Issue

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am using Elastic Search 6.8.0

[image]

My Spring Boot Version is v2.1.6.RELEASE
When I am adding

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

It is working fine,behind the scene it is using v6.4.3
v6.8.0 is also working fine.

But when I am using higher version of the client its not working,features such as search etc is giving errors,
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Can any one tell me why I cannot use version higher than 6.8.0 ? Will there be huge change in code if I upgrade my ES Server to 7+ ?

Answer (score 2):

Client version need to be compatible with cluster version ,
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.8/java-rest-high-compatibility.html

elastic 7.x had some big changes , I would suggest having a looking here to see if any features  you use were updated :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/release-notes-7.0.0.html